# Getting unique visit count, Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to perform a query that will get the unique visits of an IP within a table

My function

```
public function getViews($unique = false, $country = null, $region = null, $city = null)
{
    $query = ReferLinkVisit::where('refer_link_id', $this->id);

    if($unique) {
        $query->groupBy('ipaddr');
    }
    if($country) {
        $query->where('country', $country);
    }
    if($region) {
        $query->where('region', $region);
    }
    if($city) {
        $query->where('city', $city);
    }

    return $query->count();
}
```

The results I get:

`10 total clicks | 1 unique`

That should say 10 and 5.

For some reason, it returns multiple rows like this:

aggregate

- 1
- 1
- 6
- 1
- 1

Where instead, I thought it would count all those up and return me the total unique

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to add `->get()` in your `$query`.

Comment: Make sure that your result is come with different value for `ipaddr`, because `groupBy()` will group as one if value `ipaddr` same for results